# Application randomly bombed, WebView throws null pointer

Tags: java, android

I've reduced my application to an almost dumb state trying to figure out the issue. I'm using the AndroidStudio (IntelliJ version) for development. I've been developing just fine until just recently the application started crashing before launching it seemed. Logcat showed this:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
   'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)'
    on a null object reference
```

As stated I've reduced the application to an almost pathetic state. (No services, No receivers), and here's my Activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

The line calling the error is the "browser.loadUrl" file, and this has been working fine for the last few hours. Please note that "requestWindowFeature" must be called above super.onCreate or the application will crash.

Here's my activity (Also unedited) and my application is nothing but a webview anyway.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Did you check for browser!=null?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that the browser should not be null, I'm already aware that browser is returning null now and can't figure out why. The WebView is still in the application, as-well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed `setContentView(int layoutId)`. Without calling it your `Activity` has no widgets to look for, and `findViewById` returns null

Comment: Wow. Where did that line go! I've been going nuts for like an hour. Silly mistakes. Must have deleted it on mistake.

Comment: sometimes shit happens :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` method for `Activity`.
After setting up content view, find reference of id will be get in `Activity`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.<YOUR_LAYOUT_ID>);

    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```